# Android/Maven - mainDexClasses.txt not found

Tags: java, android, maven, android-multidex

My team and I are working on a shared Android project.  The project builds perfectly fine on my teammates' machines but it doesn't build correctly on my machine.

Two of them have Linux machines and the other has Windows. I have also have a Windows OS (Win 10 in particular).
We use IntelliJ as our IDE and Maven for the building/compiling.  We all use the same settings.xml file.

I receive the following error:

```
Short version: Don't use this.

Slightly longer version: This tool is used by mainDexClasses script to build
the main dex list.
Convert classes to Dex : C:\...\****\****-app\target

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\...\****\****-app\target\mainDexClasses.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.readPathsFromFile(Main.java:436)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:361)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I copy the file in question, mainDexClasses.txt, from one of my team mates and past it in the applicable folder the build succeeds (without cleaning).
Obviously I can't keep doing this as it is a rather quick and dirty fix.

Here is my Maven build config:  `-Denv=wiremock -Dfeatures=trunk install android:deploy android:run`

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you aware of maven standard directory layout? You should put your application/library resources in src/main/resources. See here https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The path to mainDexClasses.txt can't contain any spaces, i.e. none of the folders should have a space in the name.